# C# Printing a border around a 2D Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I'm using as a box, and I have code that generates a border around it, like this:

```
#######
#     #
#     #
#     #
#     #
#######
```

However what I don't understand is that I can have either a 0 or a 1 in the "j == ProcArea.GetUpperBound(...)" part and it works successfully without any errors or unexpected output.

```
            int[,] ProcArea = new int[rows, columns];
            //Generate border
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == ProcArea.GetUpperBound(0) || j == ProcArea.GetUpperBound(1))
                    {
                        ProcArea[i, j] = 2;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Why does this work, and what is the correct value I should be using?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of rows and columns are the same, then `GetUpperBound(0)` and `GetUpperBound(1)` are going to return the same value.

Arrays you create in C# (unless you call `Array.CreateInstance` directly) are always 0-based. So `GetUpperBound(0)` will always return `rows - 1`, and `GetUpperBound(1)` will always return `columns - 1`.

So the code will "work" regardless of which upper bound you check, although I think you'll find that if `rows != columns`, then using `GetUpperBound(0)` will create a different sized box than `GetUpperBound(1)`.

By the way, an alternate way of making your border would be:

```
var maxRow = ProcArea.GetUpperBound(0);
var maxCol = ProcArea.GetUpperBound(1);
// do top and bottom
for (int col = 0; col <= maxCol; ++col)
{
    ProcArea[0, col] = 2;
    ProcArea[maxRow, col] = 2;
}
// do left and right
for (int row = 0; row <= maxRow; ++row)
{
    ProcArea[row, 0] = 2;
    ProcArea[row, maxCol] = 2;
}
```

It's slightly more code, true, but you don't waste time checking indexes unnecessarily. Won't make a difference with small arrays, of course.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting way of doing it that I hadn't thought of. I'm not always making boxes of equal sizes though, such as 10x11 or 9x8, would that code still work for that?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx. Your array has 2 dimensions (rows and columns).

`ProcArea.GetUpperBound(0)` is equivalent to `rows - 1`

`ProcArea.GetUpperBound(1)` is equivalent to `columns - 1`